# Sturm–Liouville Orthogonality problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation

$$X''(x) - 2X'(x) + \lambda X(x) = 0$$ with boundary conditions  $$X(0) = X(a) = 0$$

I came up with eigenvalues of $\lambda_n = 1 + \frac{n^2 \pi ^2}{a^2}$ and eigenfunctions $X_n = \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})e^x$

If I put the differential equation into self adjoint form I get,

$$- \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-2x} \frac{dX}{dx} \right) = \lambda(e^{-2x})X$$

Where I would identify $w(x) = e^{-2x}$ as the weight function.

As such, I would expect

$$\int_0^aX_nX_mw(x) dx = \delta_{nm}$$

However, for the case where $n = m$ I'm not getting an answer of 1. Perhaps someone could point out my error.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error. What you have found is an orthogonal system that is not orthonormal. To normalize it let
$$
\int_0^aX_n^2\,w(x),dx=c_n.
$$
Then the orthonormal system will be
$$
\Bigl\{\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{c_n}}\Bigr\}.
$$